# Materialize Carousel height set incorrect on initial pageview

Tags: javascript, materialize

I use the [carousel function from materialize](https://materializecss.com/carousel.html) and it almost works. It seems like several people have issues with the height of the carousel (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37762139/how-to-increase-the-size-of-carousel-in-materialize-css) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49230072/how-to-change-height-of-slider-in-materialize-css)) but all solutions are working by manually changing the height of the carousel. Here is my code:

```html
<div class="carousel carousel-slider" data-indicators="true" id="carousel-one" style="display:block;">
   <div class="carousel-item" href="#one!" style="display:block;">
    <img src="abc.jpg" style="display:block;">
   </div>
   <div class="carousel-item" href="#two!" style="display:block;">
    <img src="https://www.bestellen.net/images/preview/foe2_2.jpg" style="display:block;">
   </div>
   <div class="carousel-item" href="#three!" style="display:block;">
    <img src="efg.jpg" style="display:block;">
   </div>
  </div>
```

```js
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  M.AutoInit();

  var options = {
    fullWidth: true,
    indicators: true
  };  
  
  var elems = document.querySelector('#carousel-one');
  console.log(elems)
  var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems, options);
}
})
```

For me the only issue is that the carousel has only the min-height on the first pageview, but if i refresh the page it calculates the correct height. So i would like to use this exisiting function on onload but i have no idea how to call it and which function is the right one.

```js
/**
       * Handle Throttle Resize
       * @param {Event} e
       */

    }, {
      key: "_handleResize",
      value: function _handleResize(e) {
        if (this.options.fullWidth) {
          this.itemWidth = this.$el.find('.carousel-item').first().innerWidth();
          this.imageHeight = this.$el.find('.carousel-item.active').height();
          this.dim = this.itemWidth * 2 + this.options.padding;
          this.offset = this.center * 2 * this.itemWidth;
          this.target = this.offset;
          this._setCarouselHeight(true);
        } else {
          this._scroll();
        }
      }

      /**
       * Set carousel height based on first slide
       * @param {Booleam} imageOnly - true for image slides
       */

    }, {
      key: "_setCarouselHeight",
      value: function _setCarouselHeight(imageOnly) {
        var _this65 = this;

        var firstSlide = this.$el.find('.carousel-item.active').length ? this.$el.find('.carousel-item.active').first() : this.$el.find('.carousel-item').first();
        var firstImage = firstSlide.find('img').first();
        if (firstImage.length) {
          if (firstImage[0].complete) {
            // If image won't trigger the load event
            var imageHeight = firstImage.height();
            if (imageHeight > 0) {
              this.$el.css('height', imageHeight + 'px');
            } else {
              // If image still has no height, use the natural dimensions to calculate
              var naturalWidth = firstImage[0].naturalWidth;
              var naturalHeight = firstImage[0].naturalHeight;
              var adjustedHeight = this.$el.width() / naturalWidth * naturalHeight;
              this.$el.css('height', adjustedHeight + 'px');
            }
          } else {
            // Get height when image is loaded normally
            firstImage.one('load', function (el, i) {
              _this65.$el.css('height', el.offsetHeight + 'px');
            });
          }
        } else if (!imageOnly) {
          var slideHeight = firstSlide.height();
          this.$el.css('height', slideHeight + 'px');
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, but I cannot comment as I have less than 50 reputation right now.

Have you tested your code without the use of `M.AutoInit();`?

After reading the documentation, this is an initialisation for *all* components, which could be the culprit, as you're initialising your carousel for a *second time* after this call.